# Replace scrollbar within small text area with custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to replace a standard scrollbar with a custom image (arrow graphics) that allows visitors to click on the graphics and scroll? 2 graphics (up and down arrow).

Comment: Not without rebuilding the whole scrolling functionality from scratch using JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of WebKit (Safari, Chrome) allow this via CSS.  Maybe this will be adopted by other browsers in the near future.

http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

For now, you will have to stick to JavaScript and, as others have mentioned, [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) is probably the best one around at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) in the past and it's proved very useful!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jScrollPane:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script http://studio.radube.com/html-textarea-custom-scrollbar