# Scroll Div withour Scroll bar in asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, scroll

I am having the list of users on my page in a div. I want to use scrollbars, but should not visible them on page. only Up and down arrow should be visible. i am using asp.net mvc 3. is this possible ? how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple CSS may useful for you

In view

```
 <div id="customerresult" class="itemdetailws">
 </div>
```

CSS File

```
.itemdetailws
{
    border: thin dotted #C0C0C0; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 95%;
    height: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a HTML/CSS/Javascript question.

It needs to be done via javascript, its not possible to customize a scrollbar in a way that works across the majority of browsers.

These links cover some of the CSS approaches

[How can one use scroll bar images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729713/how-can-one-use-scroll-bar-images)

[Replace scrollbar within small text area with custom scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607699/replace-scrollbar-within-small-text-area-with-custom-scrollbar)

http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

To do this using javascript, simply use an absolute div within a relative div

something like

```
<div id="container">
<div id="scrollarea">
</div>
<a id="up-arrow">&nbsp;</a>
<a id="down-arrow">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

With some css like

```
#container
{
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#scrollarea
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
height:800px;
width:280px;
}

#up-arrow
{
background-image:something;
width:20px;
height:20px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
}
```

some javascript like (using jquery)

```
var currentScroll=0;
$("#up-arrow").click(function(){
currentScroll+=20;
$("#scrollarea").css("top",currentScroll+"px");
});

$("#down-arrow").click(function(){
currentScroll-=20;
$("#scrollarea").css("top",currentScroll+"px");
});
```

Comment: ok, but this code seems using jquery. which jquery file is suitable for this ?